# How do I display database errors gracefully? (e.g. SQLSTATE[23000]: ...)

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have two unique indexes set on my users table columns (email, username) but when I try to register a new user with a taken email AND taken username, it displays an exception as expected. However, it just shows an exception on the email column, not the username:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'martynbissett@yahoo.co.uk' for key 'email_2'
```

In my code I've tried doing something like this:

```
try {

    // attempt to save

} catch(\Exception $e) {

    switch($e->getCode()) {
        case 23000:

            $this->flash->error('Email(?) address already taken'); // or is it username?
            break;

        default:
            $this->flash->error($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also, you can see I want to present a nicer error message than SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity const... so I'm catching the error code. But I don't know in any given case which column is the problem ("Email address taken" or "Username taken"?)

Do I need to perform separate queries for each of these prior during validation? If I just had one unique index (e.g. only email) then I could just rely on the code in the exception, but if I have two....

Comment: It shows the first violation it finds and **stops**. MySQL doesn't need to check anything else if there's a problem with one key in the first place. It also will be the same error code for any integrity constraint violation. You need to rework your logic. MySQL will preserve integrity on the backend but you have to write your own code to do these checks in a graceful manner to the end-user.

Comment: So this would be something I'd need to check in the PHP if I want to know specifically which field to display the appropriate error message? (e.g. "username is already taken")

Comment: Correct! You will have to `SELECT * WHERE username LIKE ? AND email LIKE ?` and then throw an error message if the resulting row count is `> 0`. If you want to tell the user _which_ value has already been taken, you will have to split that query into two separate ones.

Comment: Why an index on both fields? The username must be unique or do you insert a new record when the combination username and e-mailadress doesn't exist (and the username does)?

Answer (score 1):

Just do the validation before inserting to database. Queries to check if specified value exists are really cheap, so don't be afraid.

Database constraints will be additional protection.